# What does this piece of Scala code that teaches subtype polymorphism mean?

Tags: scala, subtyping

The following is from a ScalaZ document when I am learning about subtype polymorph in Scala.

```
scala> trait Plus[A] {
         def plus(a2: A): A
       }
defined trait Plus

scala> def plus[A <: Plus[A]](a1: A, a2: A): A = a1.plus(a2)
plus: [A <: Plus[A]](a1: A, a2: A)A
```

I do not follow the part `A <: Plus[A]`.  What is the intuition behind? In particular, the same A appears there, making me quite confused.

Comment: In more idiomatic Scala, I think this would be written `trait Plus[A] { def plus(x: A, y: A): A }; def plus[A](x: A, y: A)(implicit p: Plus[A]) { p.plus(x, y) }` (except there would be more helper definitions). You don't have to understand what I just wrote, but I would still imagine the code you've posted to be somewhat rare.

Comment: @HTNW Even with the much I also like FP. I would not call **typeclasses** more _idiomatic_ than **subtyping** _(even given I prefer the former)_. Also, I do not find nothing rare about the code that OP posted, it is just subtyping + f-bounded polymorphism, that is somewhat common

Answer (score 4):

`A <: Plus[A]` is called `F-bounded` type. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339548/scala-f-bounded-types-explanation) is good example of what it is useful for.

In your example it means that each `A` must implement `Plus`, so that each `A` can add itself to any other `A`. You need type `A` in `Plus` in order to make this trait polymorphic in type `A`.

In general, your `def plus [A <: Plus[A]]` is polymorphic by subtype, because you can call it with different implementations sub-typing `trait Plus`

Comment: It would be useful to add that `<:` is also a **type bound**. In general `A <: B` just demands that the method / class can be used with any type _(A)_ that is a subtype of B. Just that in this particular case, it was required to be an **F-Bounded**.