# Inherited return type with contravariant type parameter

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance, variance, contravariance

I have a trait with covariant type `A` that declares (among others) this method:

```scala
sealed trait MaxPQ[+U] {
...
def insert[K >: U : Ordering](v: K): this.type
...
}

abstract class AbstractMaxPQ[U : Ordering] extends MaxPQ[U]
```

I also have this mix-in that I need to use:

```scala
trait FindMin[U] {

  self: AbstractMaxPQ[U] =>
```

I am returning `this.type` because I want `Node` or `Array` based implementations of the priority queue to return current types and not `MaxPQ[U]`.

In the array based implementation I have the following:

```scala
class ArrayMaxPQ[U : Ordering : ClassTag] ...extends AbstractMaxPQ[U] with FindMin[U]{
...
override def insert[K >: U : Ordering](v: K): ArrayMaxPQ[U] = ???
...
```

this is what is auto-generated by my IDE. Of course I need this method to return `ArrayMaxPQ[K]`.
`this.type` doesn't take type parameters. Using higher-kinded types here also wouldn't work

```scala
def insert[K >: U : Ordering, G[_] <: MaxPQ[_]](v: K): G[K]
```

since `G` cannot be parameterized with `self` type in children.

I am a bit confused since this feels like a simple requirement but I cannot find language feature/syntax required to implement it.

Comment: What is wrong with `this.type`? [It works](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/FZbzhfZzRfitTAjQ3mJQ0w/1).

Comment: It return a wrong type in the concrete implementation: `ArrayMaxPQ[U]` instead of `ArrayMaxPQ[K]`.

Comment: Ah right, the simples solution would be to move all those methods into a typeclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want the return type to be wider than `this.type` but narrower than just `MaxPQ[U]`. Then try to introduce a type member

```
sealed trait MaxPQ[+U] {
  type This <: MaxPQ[U]
  // type This >: this.type <: MaxPQ[U] { type This = MaxPQ.this.This }

  def insert[K >: U : Ordering](v: K): This
}

abstract class AbstractMaxPQ[U : Ordering] extends MaxPQ[U] {
  override type This <: AbstractMaxPQ[U]
  // override type This >: this.type <: AbstractMaxPQ[U] { type This = AbstractMaxPQ.this.This }
} 

class ArrayMaxPQ[U : Ordering : ClassTag] extends AbstractMaxPQ[U] {
  override type This = ArrayMaxPQ[U]

  override def insert[K >: U : Ordering](v: K): ArrayMaxPQ[U] = ???
}
```

[Returning the "Current" Type in Scala](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html)

---

If you want the return type to be parametrized with an upper bound of `U` try to make `This` higher-kinded

```
sealed trait MaxPQ[+U] {
  type This[K >: U] <: MaxPQ[K]
  // type This[K >: U] <: MaxPQ[K] { type This[K1 >: K] = MaxPQ.this.This[K1] }

  def insert[K >: U : Ordering](v: K): This[K]
}

abstract class AbstractMaxPQ[U : Ordering] extends MaxPQ[U] {
  override type This[K >: U] <: AbstractMaxPQ[K]
  // override type This[K >: U] <: AbstractMaxPQ[K] { type This[K1 >: K] = AbstractMaxPQ.this.This[K1] }
}

class ArrayMaxPQ[U : Ordering : ClassTag] extends AbstractMaxPQ[U] {
  override type This[K >: U] = ArrayMaxPQ[K]

  override def insert[K >: U : Ordering](v: K): ArrayMaxPQ[K] = ???
}
```

Comment: But I need to return current type with `contravariant` type parameter, so `K`.

Comment: @user How? I guess `This` (aka `F`) being bounded by `this.type` is an advantage of your approach (with type parameter and self-type).

Answer (score 3):

You *can* actually use higher-kinded types to do this. It's called [F-bounded polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339548/scala-f-bounded-types-explanation).

```
sealed trait MaxPQ[+U, F[_]] { self: F[_ <: U] =>
  def insert[K >: U: Ordering](v: K): F[K]
}

abstract class AbstractMaxPQ[U: Ordering, F[_]] extends MaxPQ[U, F] {
  self: F[U] =>
}

class ArrayMaxPQ[U: Ordering: ClassTag] extends AbstractMaxPQ[U, ArrayMaxPQ] {
  override def insert[K >: U: Ordering](v: K): ArrayMaxPQ[K] = ???
}
```

[Scastie demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Qaino3mCSeWGwDW1oavFSQ)

Instead of passing `G` into `insert`, use it as a type parameter of the class/trait itself, and then make sure that `this` extends that. That's what the self-type is for (`self: F[U]`). Another useful [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-self-types-and-trait-subclasses)

Comment: That almost works - and you haven't seen this part so that's why. I will edit my initial question. In short, I also have a mixin which is based on `AbstractMaxPQ`. With your suggestion the `self: AbstractMaxPQ[U, F[_]] =>` fails to compile: `F[_] takes no type parameters, expected: one`

Comment: It was my bad, in `FindMIn` if I did just `self: AbstractMaxPQ[U, F] =>` than it works